# Skip reverse entry in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a reports table where in case of product sale I set `row_type = 1` and in case of cancellation a new row is created and `row_type = 2`, so to get either records query would be :

```
select * from table where row_type = 1;

Gives orders 1,2,3,4,5
```

and

```
select * from table where row_type = 2;

Gives orders 3,5
```

Issue is when I use the first query I have records that are sales but some of them would be cancelled as well and will have another row with `row_type = 2` so I want to ignore such records and get rows that don't have any reverse entry, is this possible in one query? So:

```
    select * from table where row_type = 1;

Gives orders 1,2,4 does not include 3,5
```

I can do a work around with 2 different result sets in php code but just wondering if one query can do the trick....!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Why not update instead of inserting a new row?

Comment: it's a reporting db system and for specific reason a new reversal entry is made in case of cancellation or refund

Comment: It's almost impossible to answer a question with so little details. Can you please share your table's structure?

Comment: Sounds like a pain in the butt to work with! But you can select where the count of same rows (aside from that column in particular) is equal to one

Comment: "but some of them" - What does that mean?

Comment: Means some orders would be cancelled ..

Comment: I mean: How do you know that two rows belong to the same order? You will probably have column to identify that. Best would be, you post the schema, a sample data set and the expected result.

Comment: two rows will have same order id as well

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a sub-SELECT with a JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE row_type = 2) as cancels
ON table.id = cancels.id
WHERE table.row_type = 1 AND cancels.id IS NULL
```

The idea is that the subselect acts like another table in your query that you can `LEFT JOIN` to. Then by having the condition `cancels.id is null`, you exclude all entries from `table` that have an entry in the subselect (which contains all cancelled entries)

This assumes:

- `id` is the sale identifier and the entry with the sale has the same `id` as the entry with the cancellation

Comment: what are we joining here?

Comment: How do you know that cancel is for the same product sale?

Comment: @Sal Oops, forgot the `ON` part

Comment: `is not null` should be `is null`, `table.row_type = 2` should be `table.row_type = 1`

Comment: @Just_Do_It You are joining your table with the result of `SELECT id FROM table WHERE row_type = 2`, imagined as a separate table

Comment: Why join to subquery? Can be direct: `LEFT JOIN table as cancels ON cancels.id = table.id AND row_type = 2`

Answer (score 0):

If table having two entries for same order it means , that order is canceled 
so you can try it .

```
SELECT * , count(order_id) AS total FROM `table` 
GROUP BY order_id  HAVING total = 1
```

Comment: No i need to select all columns and rows with row_type = 1 but if there is a reverse entry for the same order then I don't want that order to display when I use: select * from table where row_type = 1;

Comment: above query will give the orders which are not cancelled

Comment: i edited my answer , please check now , it will work